# Keep drop down value in edit mode of datagrid same even when user clicks between different controls

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, datagrid, radio-button, selectedvalue

This could be a question just related to my scenario.I have a datagrid which is Editable. One of the columns is a drop down list when in edit mode. Now completely out of this data grid I have 2 radio buttons (Open,All). (outside the grid,not within any column)Default Open is selected. Based on the selected radio button , the list for the drop down in edit mode changes. Suppose the grid is in edit mode and open is selected. A selected value of "A" is show in the drop down. This is the chosen value. Now user clicks on "All" and the list varies. "A" is no longer even present in the list when "All" is selected (works as intended). Now with the grid still in edit mode user clicks on "Open". He should now see "A" as selected value for the drop down. (When the grid was NOT in edit mode "A" value was binded to the column.So when edit is clicked drop down appears with "A" as selected value).

My question is how to save/preserve the original value that was there when the edit was clicked. User has neither hit cancel or update yet. So can I hide it in the list,making it invisible or how? Important thing is when user clicks on "All" , he should NOT see "A" in the drop down. If you need more information, please ask. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a hidden field in the grid, and set the value there when you populate the grid?

Comment: @afzalulh :Thanks. I used viewstate. I got the solution. But yours seems simpler. Will try it out as well.